# How to handle a StopIteration exception while dealing with generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

I'm working with a generator and I have the code below. I'm a little confused about its logic.

The generator in the function works fine as long as there is a 'False' at the end. Removing it causes a `StopIteration` exception when running the function.

Can anybody explain me the role of `False` here?

```
>>> def some(coll, pred= lambda x:x)
...    return next((True for item in coll if pred(item)),False)
... 
>>> some([0,'',False])
False
>>> def some(coll, pred= lambda x:x):
...     return next((True for item in coll if pred(item)))
...
>>> some([0,'',False])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
    some([0,'',False])
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 2, in some
    return next((True for item in coll if pred(item)))
StopIteration
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) is quite clear about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in a default value for the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to return if the generator expression raises a `StopIteration` exception. The `False` is the default value returned here:

> Retrieve the next item from the *iterator* by calling its [`__next__()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method. If *default* is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise [`StopIteration`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) is raised.

Raising `StopIteration` is how iterators communicate that they are done and can no longer be used to produce results. Generators are a specialised type of iterator.

You don't have to pass in `False`; any valid Python value will do. If you omit the *default* argument, you can also omit the generator parenthesis:

```
next(True for item in coll if pred(item))
```